# Get shortcode attribute outside of Wordpress

Tags: shortcode, regex

Is there a clean way to get a shortcode's attribute value outside of Wordpress's default behaviour? I am working on a single script outside a Wordpress installation, where I only do `include('../wp-load.php');` at the beginning.

In my case, I am looking to get the `"caption"` attribute from the `[caption] shortcode` and have found the best way to be is as follows, but I'm very unhappy with this.

Original post's content:

```
[caption id="attachment_1" align="alignleft" width="150" caption="I'm a wicked cool banana"]<img src="http://banana.dev/uploads/2013/07/banana.jpg" alt="Banana" title="Banana" width="150" height="150" class="size-full wp-image-1" />[/caption]
```

My script to get the caption from the shortcode:

```
// prepare full content
$content = $content_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);

// test the HTML and get the part inside
if (preg_match("/<p class=\"wp-caption-text\">(.*)<\\/p>/", $content, $matches)) {
  $caption = $matches[1];
}
```

But this can't be the best way, can it?

Please note that I'm not looking to get the image's attributes, but the shortcode's attributes.

**EDIT 1**

As s_ha_dum suggested, I tried getting the shortcode with `get_shortcode_regex()`, but then I get the following:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '[caption id="attachment_1" align="alignleft" width="150" caption="I'm a wicked cool banana"]<img src="http://banana.dev/uploads/2013/07/banana.jpg" alt="Banana" title="Banana" width="150" height="150" class="size-full wp-image-1" />[/caption]' (length=394)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'caption' (length=7)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string ' id="attachment_1" align="alignleft" width="150" caption="I'm a wicked cool banana"' (length=206)
  4 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
  5 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '<img src="http://banana.dev/uploads/2013/07/banana.jpg" alt="Banana" title="Banana" width="150" height="150" class="size-full wp-image-1" />' (length=169)
  6 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
```

Which means I still have to Regex $matches[3] to get my desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to parse the shortcodes and then regex the HTML. Use [`get_shortcode_regex()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_shortcode_regex) to parse the raw post content:

```
$content = $content_post->post_content;
preg_match_all("/$pattern/",$content,$matches);
```

Then crawl `$matches` to find your shortcode data. Use [`shortcode_parse_atts($matches[3][0])`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_parse_atts) (note *$matches[3][0]* to give the first element within the matched shortcode's attributes) to pull apart the attribute string.

Reference:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73461/21376

Comment: But I'd still have to use regex to find the `caption="I'm a wicked cool banana"` bit. Is that correct?

Comment: No, not if the caption is a shortcode attribute. Did you try the code at all>

Comment: As a matter of fact I did, yes. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Thanks for adding the `shortcode_parse_atts` there. That did it! I updated your answer, so it works.